# Send email hasnt been received

Tags: java, email, smtp, gmail, sendmail

So I have this piece of code to send an email:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String to = "mycoolreceiveremail@gmail.com";//change accordingly
    String from = "mycoolsenderemail@gmail.com";//change accordingly
    String host = "localhost";//or IP address

    //Get the session object
    Properties properties = System.getProperties();
    properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", host);
    properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    properties.put("mail.smtp.port", "25");


    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties,
            new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
        @Override
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication("mycoolsenderemail@gmail.com", "mycoolsenderpassword");
        }
    });

    //compose the message
    try {
        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
        message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to));
        message.setSubject("Ping");
        message.setText("Hello, this is example of sending email  ");

        // Send message
        Transport.send(message);
        System.out.println("message sent successfully....");

    } catch (MessagingException mex) {
        mex.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

The problem is that I manage to send it (I guess), because the message "message sent successfully...." is printed. But the problem is that I don't receive the email. I checked the mail box. What can the reason be?

Comment: gmail is a highly spam proof service. you wont be able to just send a "gmail" email from any old SMTP server. you have to send it out through a gmail SMTP server with SSL, and you might need to enable this on your account. see here: https://www.mkyong.com/java/javamail-api-sending-email-via-gmail-smtp-example/

Comment: How you tried using google's smtp server instead of your localhost? I.e. 
`properties.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
properties.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");`

Comment: it will also need tls and auth enabled